# Connecting to KVM VM via VNC

Tags: virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, vnc

I just installed KVM on centos 6.5 and after I created a VM I don't know how to access via VNC.

I used this command to create the VM:

```
virt-install --name=guest_name --arch=x86_64 --vcpus=2 --ram=5120 --os-type=linux --os-variant=rhel5 --hvm --connect=qemu:///system --network bridge:br0 --cdrom=/var/lib/libvirt/images/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso --disk path=/home/guest_name.img,size=80 --accelerate --vnc
```

What to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way to do this is to run `virt-manager` on your desktop and set it up with a remote ssh connection to the hypervisor, the server running your new virtual machine.

The hard way to do this is by running `virsh vncdisplay guest_name` on the server. This will give you VNC connection information. But, you may find this unusable as it may only be bound to 127.0.0.1, or firewalled.